# Tiling menuItems in win32 as per particular design

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a pop up menu item in win32 . I was able to create a popup menu item and then I added few icons to it. This is how its looking

[image]

sameple code

```
HMENU Controls = CreatePopupMenu();
    InsertMenu(Controls, 0 , MF_STRING, 1, L"FirstMenu00");;

    static HBITMAP bmpSource = NULL;
    bmpSource = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\Users\\mac\\bit.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    MENUITEMINFO mii{};
    mii.cbSize = sizeof(mii);
    mii.fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM_DATA;
    mii.wID = 1;
    mii.hbmpItem = bmpSource;// &paHbm[i];

    bool st = InsertMenuItem(Controls, 10, TRUE, &mii);
    std::string errSTr = GetLastErrorAsString();


 TrackPopupMenuEx(Controls, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_HORPOSANIMATION, xPos, yPos, hwnd, NULL);
```

**I am trying to arrange the menu icons in the following fashion**
Ie I am trying to create a pattern where first row has 2 icons and the next row has 3 icons .

How can I achieve the same ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use MF_MENUBREAK or MF_MENUBARBREAK flag in AppendMenu function to create a multi-column menu item. It seems that each raw has the same columns. 
Here is a sample you can refer to:\

```
HMENU hmenuPopup = CreatePopupMenu();
// Add the bitmap menu items to the menu. 
bool st = AppendMenu(hmenuPopup, MF_BITMAP, uID, (LPCWSTR)paHbm);
if (!st)
{
    ErrorExit(L"AddBitmapMenu");
}
st = AppendMenu(hmenuPopup, MF_BITMAP | MF_MENUBARBREAK, uID + 1, (LPCWSTR)LoadBitmap(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2)));
if (!st)
{
    ErrorExit(L"AddBitmapMenu");
}
```

More reference: [Menu Item Separators and Line Breaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-menus#menu-item-separators-and-line-breaks), [Displaying menu items in multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482634/displaying-menu-items-in-multiple-columns)